# How to chain groups of observables that previously were each one in a forkjoin() operation

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, rxjs

I have an orders table in mysql, each order has a number of documents associated to it, whether they are quotes, invoices, etc.  There is therefore a second table called "documents", which has a "document_id" primary key and a "order_id" foreign key; In a similar fashion, I have another case for the different checks that technicians do to every vehicle, then another table for vehicle pictures.  I am creating a web service using Node and Express that needs to return a json that similar to this...

```
[
  {
    "order_id": 1003,
    "customer_id": 8000,
    "csi": 90,
    "date_admitted": "2016-10-28T05:00:00.000Z",
    "plates": "YZG-5125",
    ...
    documents: {
       "type": "invoice",
       "number": "1234",
       ...
    },
    checks: {
       "scanner": "good",
       "battery": "average",
       ...
    },
    vehicle_pictures: {
       "title": "a title...",
       "path": "the file path"
       ...
    }
  },
  {
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

As you can see, it is necessary to do three queries for each order, one for checks, another for documents and a third for pictures, then I need to add these sub results to the order for finally return the array in the response.

This would be a very easy task to do in the old world of synchronous programming, however due to the asynchronous nature of the query() method in the connection object of the mysql library, this threats to become a real hell.

In a situation where I would have to process a single order, using RxJS library on the server with a forkJoin() would suffice to process all three results at once, what I am not sure is how to "chain" every order (with a forkJoin for managing the 3 queries), so everything gets process and at the end I can call res.json(result) with everything neatly assembled.

Note: I want to solve this with RxJS instead of using a sync library package like node-mysql-libmysqlclient. The reason basically is that the "right" way to do this in an async language like Node JS is go async. Also I want to use RxJS and not async, q promises, or any other library since Observables seem to be the absolute winner in the async solutions contest and also want to be consistent in all the solutions I develop, so this question is mostly oriented for RxJS masters.

Also every single question I have found in so similar to this has the classical "purist" reply saying that if you are using Node you "should" use asynchronous and don't think in synchronous solutions. So this is a challenge for those that defend that position, since this (I think) is one of those cases where sync in Node makes sense, however I really want to learn how to do this with RxJS instead of thinking that this is impossible, which I am sure is not.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? That will net better quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood things correctly, you have some data that you want to to use to gather additional data from the database via async operations. You want to build a combined dataset consisting of the original data and the additional information that the subsequent queries have returned.

As you have mentioned, you can use `forkJoin` to wait for multiple operations to complete before proceeding. You have to do this for each item in the data sequence and then use `switchMap` to merge the result back into the original stream.

Have a look at the [following example jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bijihefala/1/edit?js,console) that demonstrate how this can be done:

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, init: 'a' },
  { id: 2, init: 'b' },
  { id: 3, init: 'c' }
]

function getA(id) {
  return Rx.Observable.timer(1000)
    .map(() => {
      return { id, a: 'abc' }
    })
    .toPromise();
}

function getB(id) {
  return Rx.Observable.timer(1500)
    .map(() => {
      return { id, b: 'def' }
    })
    .toPromise();
}

Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
  .take(data.length)
  .map(id => data[id])
  .do(data => { console.log(`query id ${data.id}`)})
  .switchMap((data) => {
    return Rx.Observable.forkJoin(getA(data.id), getB(data.id), (a, b) => {
      console.log(`got results for id ${data.id}`);
      return Object.assign({}, data, a, b);
    });
  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```